# Margin-top not working on div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I'm so confused by why `margin-top` will not work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-extended-blog">
    <div class="offers-for-week">
        <h1 class="title offers-for-this-week">offers for this week</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <img src="img/extended_blog_pic.jpg" alt="image of recipe">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div><!-- /.offers-for-week -->
</div><!-- /.container-extended-blog -->
```

SCSS:

```
.container-extended-blog {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    background-color: $blue-ot;
    width: 350px; 
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    p {
        font-family: $content-font;
        color: $icon-font-color;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `position: relative;` which I find usually works whenever something like this happens, however I have no idea why this isn't working, and would really like to understand!

Comment: You haven't actually applied any margin

Comment: margin-top where you set ?

Comment: I can't see a `margin-top` used... also, you shouldn't nest CSS.  Instead of `p` use `.container-extended-blog p`

Comment: Can you create a demo?

Comment: Oh I tried top: as well, and didn't change it back, neither work still...

Comment: I am actually using scss, so I think it's ok to nest!

Comment: @zkanoca, I do not believe it is a good idea to change the code provided by the OP.  **YOU** have absolutely no idea if that is a typo when creating the question, or whether that is part of the problem.  Changing it puts everybody else on a [wild goose chase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild-goose_chase).  I have rolled back the question to the original

Comment: @freefaller OK. Let's ask for the OP to change if it is a typo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KeepC32/JGUJ5/

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to coding, I am an apprentice and have only been coding for 3 months... I just created a jsfiddle and it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `position:absolute;` to `.container-extended-blog`

```
.container-extended-blog {
top: 200px;
margin-left: 300px;
background-color: $blue-ot;
width: 350px; 
height: 450px;
overflow: hidden;
position:absolute;
}
```

**OR**

Change `top: 200px;` to `margin-top: 200px;`

```
.container-extended-blog {
margin-top: 200px;
margin-left: 300px;
background-color: $blue-ot;
width: 350px; 
height: 450px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

see fiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/Q5xdf/

Comment: Adding position: absolute; worked! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @user3541921 then mark as answer to help for others who will encounter similar problem in the future.

Comment: I was waiting for Stackoverflow to let me, it said wait 5 mins first! Thank you!